# How wide should be random numbers so it is virtually impossible that you repeat two of them?

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic

Certain system is supposed to spawn objects with unique IDs. That system will run in different computers without connection between them; yet no ID collision can happen. The only way to implement this is generating random numbers. How wide should be the those so you can consider it is virtually impossible for a collision to ever happen?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier Sounds like you're describing GUIDs

Comment: Is 1 in a septillion cases considered "virtually impossible"? If you define the probability that is acceptable for you then it should be possible to give you the answer.

Comment: That answers my question and even suggests a good value (128 bits). Thank you! (I wonder why the downvote, though.)

Comment: JF Sebastian is an idealist, and you are looking for a pragmatic answer.

Comment: `The only way to implement this is generating random numbers` — Can you explain why? For example, what's wrong with sequential numbers? If each computer has a unique ID, then the two could be joined together to form a globally unique value.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Which is essentially what a UUID/GUID does.  The randomness is combined with constant data from the machine identity, to ensure uniqueness.

Answer (score 5):

This is basically a generalization of the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

[This probability table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table) can help you to figure out how many bits you are going to need in order to achieve the probability you desire - based on `p` - desired probability, and `#elements` that are going to be "hashed" (generated).

Answer (score 1):

In your question you mentioned:

> The only way to implement this is generating random numbers

No, this is **NOT** the only way to do this. In fact this is one of the ways **NOT** to do it.

There is already a well known and widely used method for doing something like this that you yourself are using right now: adding a prefix (or postfix, doesn't matter). The prefix is called many things by many systems: Ethernet and WiFi call it vendor id. In TCP/IP it's called a subnet (technically it's called a "network").

The idea is simple. Say for example you want to use a 32 bit number for your global id. Reserve something like 8 bits to identify which system it's on and the rest can simply be sequential numbers within each system.

Stealing syntax from IPv4 for a moment. Say system 1 has an id of 1. And system 2 has an id of 2. Therefore ids form system 1 will be in the range between 1.0.0.0 - 1.255.255.255 and ids from system 2 will be between 2.0.0.0 - 2.255.255.255.

That's just an example. There's nothing that forces you to waste so many bits for system id. In fact, IPv4 is itself no longer organized by byte boundaries. You can instead use 4 bits as system id and 28 bits for individual ids. You can also use 64 bits if you need more ids or go the IPv6 route and use 128 bits (in which case you can definitely afford to waste a byte or two for system id).

Because each system cannot generate an id that's generated by another system no collision will ever occur before the ids overflow.

If you need the ids to look "random" use a hashing algorithm. Good hashing algorithms such as SHA1 and CRC are guaranteed to never collide if your data is of a fixed size below the size of the hash. For example, SHA1 is 160 bits so if your id generation system is less than 160 bits internally then the SHA1 hash of ids will never collide. The caveat being that you must use all 160 bits. Turncating the SHA1 will cause collisions. For 32 bit ids CRC32 is a perfect fit while there's also CRC64 if you want to generate 64 bit ids.

Comment: You are considering the systems have unique IDs, that is not the case.

Comment: Why is it not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Guids use 2^128 and the likelyhood of collision is negligible

Comment: To avoid cargo cult programming, it might be useful to understand some concepts behind the tools, not just use them blindly. In particular, it might help to know the probability of collision and how it can be calculated in this case.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian he did link me to the article that had everything I needed to learn, though. Just forgot on this particular answer.